# How to convert nested dictionary to list with key orders

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I want to make a list out of the nested dictionary:

```
 {'Name': {'20': 'Paul Merrill', '21': 'Brynne S. Barr', }, 
 'Phone': {'20': '1-313-739-3854', '21': '939-4818', }, 
 'Address': {'20': '916-8087 Vehicula Rd.', '21': '878-2231 Suspendisse Rd.', },
 'City': {'20': 'Le Mans', '21': 'Wilhelmshaven',}
```

to a list with '20' as the identifier, so it will be something like this:

```
['20', 'Paul Merril', '1-313-739-3854', '916-8087 Vehicula Rd.', 'Le Mans']
```

I have tried to use value and key options, but they don't seem to work. 
Could someone help me with this?

Comment: This should be pretty straightforward. Please post your code so we can give specific advice.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
L = [v['20'] for k, v in d.items()] 
#alternative if some key 20 is missing
L = [v.get('20') for k, v in d.items()]
```

Or solution from @Henry Yik, thank you:

```
L = [v.get("20") for v in d.values()]
print (L)
['Paul Merrill', '1-313-739-3854', '916-8087 Vehicula Rd.', 'Le Mans']
```

If also need prepend `20`:

```
L = ['20'] + L
```

Or:

```
L = ['20', *L]

print (L)
['20', 'Paul Merrill', '1-313-739-3854', '916-8087 Vehicula Rd.', 'Le Mans']
```

Comment: Or `[v.get("20") for v in d.values()]` since the key is not required.

Comment: I think @Henry's main point is instead of `k, v in d.items()`, use `v in d.values()`, since `k` is not required.

Comment: @wjandrea - yop, agree. ;)